# Subsetting a dataframe based on daily maxima

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an excel csv with a date/time column and a value associated with that date/time. I'm trying to write a script that will go through this format (see below), and find 1) the maximum value per day, and 2) the time on that day that the maximum occurs. Preferably R would return both values to me in a new dataframe.

The data looks something like this:

```
         V1    V2 V3
1  5/1/2012  3:00  1
2  5/1/2012  6:00  2
3  5/1/2012  9:00  5
4  5/1/2012 12:00  3
5  5/1/2012 15:00  6
6  5/1/2012 18:00  2
7  5/1/2012 21:00  1
8  5/2/2012  0:00  2
9  5/2/2012  3:00  3
10 5/2/2012  6:00  6
11 5/2/2012  9:00  4
12 5/2/2012 12:00  6
13 5/2/2012 15:00  7
14 5/2/2012 18:00  9
15 5/2/2012 21:00  1
```

So the function I'm envisioning would return:

```
1 5/1/2012 15:00 6
2 5/2/2012 18:00 9
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go:

```
dat.str <- '         V1    V2 V3
1  5/1/2012  3:00  1
2  5/1/2012  6:00  2
3  5/1/2012  9:00  5
4  5/1/2012 12:00  3
5  5/1/2012 15:00  6
6  5/1/2012 18:00  2
7  5/1/2012 21:00  1
8  5/2/2012  0:00  2
9  5/2/2012  3:00  3
10 5/2/2012  6:00  6
11 5/2/2012  9:00  4
12 5/2/2012 12:00  6
13 5/2/2012 15:00  7
14 5/2/2012 18:00  9
15 5/2/2012 21:00  1'

dat <- read.table(textConnection(dat.str), row.names=1, header=TRUE)

do.call(rbind, 
        by(dat, INDICES=dat$V1, FUN=function(x) tail(x[order(x$V3), ], 1)))
```

Comment: thanks, works perfectly for the example I provided. Can you quickly explain the ' symbol that you used?

Comment: do I need to have that included to use the textConnection function?

Comment: textConnection takes a string and returns a connection to it.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using the plyr package, which I find very elegant for problems like this.

```
dat.str <- '         V1    V2 V3
1  5/1/2012  3:00  1
2  5/1/2012  6:00  2
3  5/1/2012  9:00  5
4  5/1/2012 12:00  3
5  5/1/2012 15:00  6
6  5/1/2012 18:00  2
7  5/1/2012 21:00  1
8  5/2/2012  0:00  2
9  5/2/2012  3:00  3
10 5/2/2012  6:00  6
11 5/2/2012  9:00  4
12 5/2/2012 12:00  6
13 5/2/2012 15:00  7
14 5/2/2012 18:00  9
15 5/2/2012 21:00  1'

dat <- read.table(textConnection(dat.str), row.names=1, header=TRUE)

library(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(V1), function(x){
   x[which.max(x$V3), ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with time series data, I suggest you use a time series class like `zoo` or `xts`

```
dat <- read.table(text="         V1    V2 V3
1  5/1/2012  3:00  1
2  5/1/2012  6:00  2
3  5/1/2012  9:00  5
4  5/1/2012 12:00  3
5  5/1/2012 15:00  6
6  5/1/2012 18:00  2
7  5/1/2012 21:00  1
8  5/2/2012  0:00  2
9  5/2/2012  3:00  3
10 5/2/2012  6:00  6
11 5/2/2012  9:00  4
12 5/2/2012 12:00  6
13 5/2/2012 15:00  7
14 5/2/2012 18:00  9
15 5/2/2012 21:00  1", row.names=1, header=TRUE)

require("xts")
# create an xts object
xobj <- xts(dat[, 3], order.by=as.POSIXct(paste(dat[, 1], dat[, 2]), format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))
```

If you just wanted to get the daily maximums, and you were okay with using the last time of the day as the index, you could use `apply.daily`

```
apply.daily(xobj, max)
#                    [,1]
#2012-05-01 21:00:00    6
#2012-05-02 21:00:00    9
```

To keep the timestamps at which it occurs, you could do this

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(xobj, "days"), function(x) x[which.max(x), ]))
#                    [,1]
2012-05-01 15:00:00    6
2012-05-02 18:00:00    9
```

`split(xobj, "days")` creates a list with one day's data in each element.

`lapply` applies a function to each day; the function, in this case, simply returns the `max` observation for each day.  The `lapply` call will return a `list` of xts objects.  To turn it back into 
a single xts object, use `do.call`.

`do.call(rbind, X)` constructs a call to rbind using each element of the list.  It is equivalent to `rbind(X[[1]], X[[2]], ..., X[[n]])`

Answer (score 1):

For another alternative, you could use `data.table`:

```
dat_table <- data.table(dat)

dat_table [ , list(is_max = V3==max(V3), V2, V3), by= 'V1'][which(is_max),][,is_max :=NULL]
```

**EDIT** as per @MattDowle's comment

```
dat_table[, .SD[which.max(V3)], by=V1]
```

For an even simpler `data.table` solution.

Comment: That's an interesting solution, I like the compounding. But in this case there is a much simpler way: `DT[,.SD[which.max(V3)],by=V1]`.

Comment: Much simpler. I thought there had to be.