# Extract the indices of the top nth values for each element in dataframe

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, plyr

I have a timestamp entry of 4 students answering an online questionnaire in a dataframe. The 1st column is Time, the 2nd is the student's id (id: 1,2,3,4). Below is a simulated dataframe:

```
DF <- data.frame(cbind(Time=1:60, ID=sample(1:4, 60, replace=T)))
```

I'm trying to extract the indices of the first 5th entries for each student to extract the timestamp of entry. This should return an array of 20 values in it (4 students X first 5 entries).

I've tried using rank(), order(), with the mix of ddply() but wasn't successful. Any good suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: see my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109828/subsetting-a-dataframe-based-on-daily-maxima

Comment: Thanks, @mplourde! I totally missed that tail() can specify custom length!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer mplourde gave in the comment is great, but you can do this with `plyr` too:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(DF, .(ID), function(x) data.frame(Time_sorted=tail(sort(x$Time))))
```

and the `by` version:

```
do.call(rbind, by(DF, DF$ID, function(x) tail(x[order(x$Time),])))
```

Comment: `ddply(DF, .(ID), function(x) data.frame(Time_sorted=tail(sort(x$Time),5)))` if you want the first 5th entries and result set of 20.

Comment: Thanks @Justin, @John! I guess for the top 5 entries, `head()` should be used instead of `tail()`,which gives:
`ddply(DF, .(ID), function(x) data.frame(Time_sorted=head(sort(x$Time),5)))`

Comment: @SeanM actually, you do want `tail(..., 5)`.  Sort puts things in ascending order by default.  If you use `head` you want to add `decreasing=TRUE` to the `sort` call.