# summing based on daily maxima values

Tags: r, dataframe, max, subset

I'm trying to write an R script that will go through a dataframe that i import from an excel spreadsheet (see below for format), and find the sum of daily values until the daily maxima (and including the daily maxima)

The data looks something like this:

```
5/1/2012  0:00  0         
5/1/2012  3:00  1
5/1/2012  6:00  2
5/1/2012  9:00  5
5/1/2012 12:00  3
5/1/2012 15:00  6
5/1/2012 18:00  2
5/1/2012 21:00  1
5/2/2012  0:00  2
5/2/2012  3:00  3
5/2/2012  6:00  6
5/2/2012  9:00  4
5/2/2012 12:00  6
5/2/2012 15:00  7
5/2/2012 18:00  9
5/2/2012 21:00  1
```

So the function I'm envisioning would return:

```
1 5/1/2012 15:00 17
2 5/2/2012 18:00 35
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you not want the 1st line to be `5/1/2012 0:00 2`?

Comment: it could read that too, what I've posted about is just an example. I've edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Looks like this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109828/subsetting-a-dataframe-based-on-daily-maxima)

Comment: Erm, what was wrong with the answer provided last time? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11109989/889604

Comment: It does, but this time I'm looking for a function to sum until the daily maximum.

Comment: @ChrisW those answers were great. I was looking for advice summing all daily values up until the daily maximum in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very minor tweak to an answer given by @Thierry in your last question

```
dat.str <- '5/1/2012  0:00  0 
5/1/2012  3:00  1
5/1/2012  6:00  2
5/1/2012  9:00  5
5/1/2012 12:00  3
5/1/2012 15:00  6
5/1/2012 18:00  2
5/1/2012 21:00  1
5/2/2012  0:00  2
5/2/2012  3:00  3
5/2/2012  6:00  6
5/2/2012  9:00  4
5/2/2012 12:00  6
5/2/2012 15:00  7
5/2/2012 18:00  9
5/2/2012 21:00  1
'

dat <- read.table(textConnection(dat.str))

library(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(V1), function(x){
   sum(x[1:(which.max(x$V3)), "V3"])
})
```

I would say also that you havent shown any initiative or any work.
EDIT @John yes the OP changed the data slightly since last question have edited to reflect this.

Comment: Yeesh, some of us are newer to R and struggle with this stuff. Even when you know exactly what you want, a small syntax error can keep you from getting what you want. Sorry, and thanks for the help.

Comment: @BrettMichael What small syntax error? You didn't show us any code. That makes it look like you haven't tried anything.  There is more to programming than knowing what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure this works. `duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed`